# Powershell connecting to Sharepoint online using Active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sharepoint-online

To start, I am using Windows 7, I am a full adminstrator on this machine
I have tried other machines and ran as an administrator as well

I am only a sharepoint site collection admin

In powershell we connect to Sharepoint online.  during this process, if I use Connect-PnPOnline -Url $masterSiteUrl -useweblogin, I get prompted for a username, however the next screen is blank and stays there.

when I do a view source of that page I get
d>Redirecting....myshn.net/certcheck" method="POST">

I do have scripting enabled and sometimes I get a certificate issue, I have clicked "Install Certificate" although I am not sure what it did, but it still doesnt work
Ive also tried -SPOManagementShell and -ClearTokenCache
 and get the following error
Connect-PnPOnline : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline -Url $masterSiteUrl -useweblogin -spoManagementShel ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline

Comment: This is an Azure/O365 auth issue, not a PowerShell specific one. Connecting to O365 resources has nothing to do with your on-Prem AD or AD user account or what OS you are using. It has to do with your Azure and SPO identity and permissions. If you go directly to SPO, via the Azure portal, how are you logging in? You need to be properly configured. [See the docs on that topic](https://www.bing.com/search?q=connect+to+sharepoint+online+powershell&form=ANSPH1&refig=420390f971d74633e525593a798ad91f&sp=1&qs=AS&pq=connect+to+sharepoint+online+&sk=PRES1&sc=8-29&cvid=420390f971d74633e525593a798ad91f).

Comment: When I go to the azure site it logs me in automatically with my AD company account, no password needed, I just enter my email

Comment: This just means that they have eSSO enabled in Azure Portal via your internal IdP but you had to hit a login page to pass creds (which takes your creds, passes the request to AAD, then this passes this to your IdP, verifies you and allows you in). This is not the same thing when connecting with PowerShell. You are n ot going through a login page, thus the eSSO not being a thing. You must pass explicit credentials in your connection request to Azure/O365 when using automation. See teh MS docs for logging into Azure/O365 using PowerShell.

Comment: when logging in with powershell,
I have tried the following 
Username = email and password = ADPassword 
Username = email, password = CompanyName 
username = email, password =""

Answer (score 0):

See this:

> [Connect to all Office 365 services in a single Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-all-office-365-services-in-a-single-windows-powershell-window)

and this...

> [Connect to all Office 365 Services PowerShell - Supports MFA too](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-Script-to-4081ec0f)
>
> Using our All-in-One PowerShell script, you can connect to all Office
>   365 Services using a single cmdlet. It supports both MFA and non-MFA
>   account -Exchange Online -Azure AD -SharePoint Online -Skype for
>   Business Online -Security & Compliance Center -Teams
>
> [Download: ConnectO365Services.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-Script-to-4081ec0f/file/225256/1/ConnectO365Services.ps1)
>
> [O365_Logon 1.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/O365_Logon/1.1)
>
> O365 logon cmdlets to assist IT administrators. In this module, there
>   are several cmdlets that simplify the process of logging onto various
>   O365 components.

Comment: I believe you need elevated access on the O365 site for this correct?

Comment: Nope, you just need auth and the correct rights/privileges to act on a target, in your case SPO. SPO right/privs have nothing to do with PowerShell and Powershell would never know or need to know about them.

Comment: I am still looking into this, it currently is not working.